# Shell Script: How to enforce display of previous query if a statement is true?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've wrote a script witch automatically install NRPE, one of the steps the script is doing is asking you how would you like to install the daemon `(standalone/xinetd)`.
If the user chooses `xinetd`, I'm running a check if the file `/etc/init.d/xinetd` exists and if not, the script prints "Xinetd is not installed!" and right after it a `break`.

Here's the relevant portion of the script:

```
echo "How would you like to configure the NRPE daemon?"
select DMN in 'Xinetd' 'Standalone Daemon'; do
if [ "$DMN" = "Xinetd" ];
  then
                DMNMODE="xinetd"
                if [ -e $XINETDSVC ]; then
        cat << EOF > $XINETDFILE
service nrpe
{
        flags           = REUSE
        type            = UNLISTED
        port            = $NRPEPORT
        socket_type     = stream
        wait            = no
        user            = $NGUSER
        group           = $NGGROUP
        server          = /usr/sbin/nrpe
        server_args     = -c $NRPECFG --inetd
        log_on_failure  += USERID
        disable         = no
        only_from       = 127.0.0.1 $NAGIOSSRV
}
EOF
        $XINETDSVC restart
                else
                        echo "Xinetd is not installed!"
                        break
                fi
break
elif [ "$DMN" = "Standalone Daemon" ];
        then
                DMNMODE="daemon"
                chkconfig nrpe on ; $NRPESVC start
break
fi
done
```

The idea is that if the file is not present which means that `xinetd` is not installed, I want the script to ask the user again how he would like to install the service.
But in action, when I run the script, if I choose `xinetd` while `xinetd` is not installed, then the script prints the "Xinetd is not installed" and then continues to the next step in the script.

I thought that putting a `break` inside the `if statement` will break and take the user back to the last question... but it doesn't, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `break` only when the input supplied is valid.

`break` will break out of the `select`.

Don't `break` and `select` will loop again.

Comment: Replace the `break` with a `continue`.

Comment: @ItaiGanot Remove the `break` before the `elif`. Remove the `break` after `echo Xinetd is not installed!`. Add a `break` after `$XINETDSVC restart`. You want to only `break` when you can do what they said, not all the time.